# R markdown / Plotly R with LaTeX unable to generate plot and get error on a file name with hyphen

Tags: pdftex, r, knitr, rmarkdown

I am using LaTeX for some formatting, and trying to generate a PDF file with a `plotly` R plot as a png. The following piece of code gives me an error as show below. It seems like a problem with the hyphen in the auto generated file name? Any ideas?

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
- \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \setlength{\headheight}{100pt}
- \setlength{\textheight}{530pt}
- \rhead{\textsc{\bfseries \large MY \\Plots}}
- \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
---
\begin{tcolorbox}[colbacktitle=Fuchsia,
fonttitle=\centering\Large\bfseries\color{white},
colback=white,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,
title=PLOT INFORMATION]\parskip1em

\centering

```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, message = FALSE, warn = FALSE}
  library(plotly)
  p <- mtcars %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
  export(p, file = tmpFile)
```
\end{tcolorbox}
````

Error message is as follows:

```
processing file: myfile.Rmd
output file: myfile.knit.md

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.103 ![](myfile_
                           files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png)<!-- -->
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 34563 strings out of 493029
 658943 string characters out of 6136233
 733691 words of memory out of 5000000
 37639 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 25977 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 63i,3n,101p,10496b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Warning: Error in : Failed to compile myfile.tex. See myfile.log for more info.
  [No stack trace available]
```

I did install `webshot` and `phantomJS`, and set the path correctly as prescribed in this post:
[Plotly as png in knitr/rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268152/plotly-as-png-in-knitr-rmarkdown)

NOTE: I am using a `render()` call in a Shiny app to knit this thing into PDF document as follows:

```
render('myfile.Rmd', pdf_document())
```

This call is what then gives me the above error.

Answer (score 0):

It renders on my computer. Are you also making sure ggplot2 is installed? I am not too familiar with Latex, but I am using Mac OSX and TinyTex. I also am using `--pdf-engine pdflatex`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your error message suggests that your `Shiny` app is trying to include a graphic with `![](myfile_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png)` but use of the underscore, `_`,  in the folder name, `myfile_files` is being interpreted as the markup for a subscript, which must be written in math mode surrounded by `$`. That's why you get `Missing $ inserted.` I suggest you look for a way that does not involve writing the underscore.

I get two other errors that need to be corrected. The first is an options clash loading `xcolor`. You load it with `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` but this clashes with the options set when you do `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`. This can be fixed by adding `classoption: dvipsnames` to your YAML header. This was previously answered here: [Knitr hook to add code before \documentclass line in tex file to avoid options clash with xcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393826/)

The second problem is the syntax for putting the code chunk in a `tcolorbox`. The correct syntax in `Rmd` is `\tcolorbox` ...code chunk... `\endtcolorbox` as reported here: [How can I get Rchunks to render inside tcolorbox?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509510/)

````
---
title: "TeX.SE"
classoption: dvipsnames
output:
  pdf_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \setlength{\headheight}{100pt}
- \setlength{\textheight}{530pt}
- \rhead{\textsc{\bfseries \large MY \\Plots}}
- \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
---
\tcolorbox
\centering
```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, message = FALSE, warn = FALSE}
  library(plotly)
  p <- mtcars %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
  export(p, file = tmpFile)
```
\endtcolorbox
````

[image]

Comment: You are correct that some process is generating that temporary file name with an underscore. It might be the `render` function or the `knit` function that gets called underneath. I can't seem to be able to control that file name. Any other possible solutions to set an option to not use `_` or such?